# Does converting this Objective-C code from a Parse tutorial into Swift equate to the same check

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I have been using Parse in an app and in the tutorial for using their pre-made log in and sign up views, there is a check to see whether the log in process should start based on the username and password fields. in objective-c the code looks like this

```
// Sent to the delegate to determine whether the log in request should be submitted to the server.
- (BOOL)logInViewController:(PFLogInViewController *)logInController shouldBeginLogInWithUsername:(NSString *)username password:(NSString *)password {
    // Check if both fields are completed
    if (username && password && username.length != 0 && password.length != 0) {
        return YES; // Begin login process
}
[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Missing Information"
                      message:@"Make sure you fill out all of the information!"
                      delegate:nil
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"ok"
                      otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
    return NO; // Interrupt login process
}
```

The main part I am concerned with is the if statement `if (username && password && username.length != 0 && password.length != 0)` this does not convert over directly into swift so far as I can tell. The best that I could make it work was checking the logic the opposite of how they have it as shown below in Swift

```
  func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String!, password: String!) -> Bool
    {
      // Check to make sure both fields are filled out
      if(username.isEmpty | password.isEmpty)
      {
        let alertView: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "Missing Information", message: "Please make sure all fields are filled out!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "ok")
        alertView.show()

        return false
      }

      return true
  }
```

I haven't been able to find anything if someone has already directly converted this function into Swift. My main concern though is whether the checks equate or not. I feel that my Swift conversion might not cover the same checks as the Obj-C. I would really appreciate some help on whether or not it does actually check equally.

Edit:
The main problem is that you can't check for equality with a string like the obj-c in Swift. It says that the string cannot be used as a boolean. But even with typecasting I am not sure if it would work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if usrEntered != "" && pwdEntered != "" && emlEntered != "" {
        //insert code here for successfull login
    }
```

That should be what your looking for.

Comment: That does not work because you are trying to compare a String where it is expecting a Bool. I stated that in my above explanation.

Comment: Why don't you insert the check before you run the login function? That way you won't have this issue

Comment: Because I am working with a specific API and the above code is required for the delegate protocol

Answer (score 0):

```
if(countElements(username) != 0 && countElements(password) != 0){
    return true;
}
```

This should be what you are looking for.

Comment: I tried this with String.utf16count (It's something like that) and I still got the same error and I know that countElements works in a similar fashion. Have you tested that?

Comment: tested this, does not work. Says it is not a known binary operator. I believe my solution might be the only one that actually works so far. I would be interested to see someone else's working version though

Comment: No it does not work it raises two errors but it is essentially the same thing. It seems you cannot compare a string in Swift like a bool. I believe the .isEmpty is the only way to check for an empty string

Answer (score 0):

```
func logInViewController(logInController: PFLogInViewController!, shouldBeginLogInWithUsername username: String!, password: String!) -> Bool {
    if (username != nil && password != nil && !username.isEmpty && !password.isEmpty) {
        return true
    }
    let alertView = UIAlertView(title: "Missing Information", message: "Make sure you fill out all of the information!", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alertView.show()
    return false
}
```

Here is your direct translation. The checks you were missing from the Objective-C were the "username != nil && password != nil". However, in my version of Xcode, the parameters are not optionals so this code will not compile. You can actually take out the checks for nil because the username and password parameters are not type "String?" (optional) and therefore they are guaranteed to be there.